# What is the differnce between page object model and page factory in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

As it seems page object model and page factory is doing same thing. So i am confused.

```
IpmObjectInitializer initialize = new IpmObjectInitializer(driver.getWebDriver());
```

// Initialize elements in BatchCreationPageFactory class

```
batchCreationPageFactory = initialize.getBatchCreationPageFactoryObj();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Page Object` is a class that represents a web page and hold the functionality and members.

```
public class LogInPage
{
    private WebElement userName;
    private WebElement password;

    public LogInPage() {
    }

    public void locateElements() {
        userName = driver.findElement(By.id("userName"));
        password = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
    }

    public void doLogIn() {
        userName.sendKeys("qwe");
        password.sendKeys("123");
    }
}
```

`Page Factory` is a way to initialize the web elements you want to interact with within the page object when you create an instance of it.

```
public class LogInPage
{
    @FindBy(id="userName")
    private WebElement userName;

    @FindBy(id="password")
    private WebElement password;

    public LogInPage() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this); // initialize the members like driver.findElement()
    }

    public void doLogIn() {
        userName.sendKeys("qwe");
        password.sendKeys("123");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Page Object Model (POM)**

1.. POM is a Design pattern which segregates selenium code based on pages.

Ex: Create a separate java class for the Login page, one more class for Home Page etc.

2.. A Page Object Model is a way of representing an application in a test framework. For every ‘page’ in the application, you create a Page Object to reference the ‘page’.

**Page Factory**

1.. Advanced concept ( POM + new features )or

1. Elements are identified using @FindBy or @FindBys Annotation
2. Initialism all the elements declared in Point#1 at a time.

( in POM, initialization happens on the fly )

PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);

2.. A Page Factory is one way of implementing a Page Object Model. In order to support the Page Object pattern, WebDriver’s support library contains a factory class.